# How to reduce dynamic library loading time?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

I have a question about reducing the dynamic linking time.

I've got a binary which links with 189 shared libraries. I profiled the execution with `perf` tool and the dynamic linker (ld.so) takes up 40% of the runtime of my program, approximately 90 milliseconds of time.

Is there any way to optimize dynamic library loading time, or am I forced to use static linking?

I run this program a lot of times.

Comment: `ld` (the linker) doesn't use _any_ time to run. It's `ld.so` the loader which does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Avoid C++ constructors in libraries as they cause delays for running constructors themselves, for resolving symbols and loading code from hard drive
2. Minimize number of exported symbols by compiling libraries with `-fvisibility=hidden` (and selectively using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` for symbols that you do want to export)
3. Use `--as-needed` to minimize library dependencies
4. Make sure that lazy binding is enabled (i.e. `LD_BIND_NOW` is not set and library is not compiled with `-Wl,-z,now`)
5. Finally you can use the [Prelink](https://linux.die.net/man/8/prelink) tool to precompute symbol offsets statically
6. If some of your libraries are only loaded rarely or in specific use-cases, you can delay their loading until first use. There are builtin options for this in Windows (`/DELAYLOAD`) and macOS (`-lazy-l`) and on Linux you can use [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so).

Library load time can be measured by exporting `LD_DEBUG=statistics`

Comment: I think prelinking is the answer. I analysed the load times with LD_DEBUG=statistics and it seems that relocating takes a significant amount of time.

Comment: @r3drock Unfortunately Prelink support has been dropped from Glibc.

Answer (score 1):

The loading time depends on several factors: the time needed to transfer the libraries from media storage to memory, the number of symbols you are linking with... Here are some suggestions:

1. If you use [dlopen()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), you can set the lazy binding flag (**RTLD_LAZY**)
2. Make sure to have a ld.so.cache up to date using [ldconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) (and update ld.so.conf if necessary) to improve the library search time. Using [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) may help to see how many attempts are done to find the library files. Check also **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable.
3. Make sure that the **LD_BIND_NOW** environment variable is not set to make the dynamic linker ([ld.so](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so)) run in lazy mode

### Tips

- As the some part of the libraries (especially the readonly sections like code) are shared between the running processes. You can arrange to have a background process dynamically linked with the libraries to save some dynamic linking time for any new created processes using the same libraries as most of them will be already loaded in memory.
- You can launch your program under `strace` to check if the libraries are found directly at their right place or if the dynamic linker is doing several tries to find them. This usually means that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is wrongly set or should not be set at all. This may also mean that the linker's command line is badly set a build time.
  For example, here is a `strace` result of the startup of `/bin/ls` executable. Libraries like *libm* or *libpam* are found at their right place but the *libc* requires several tries in several directories to be finally found in */lib*:

```
[root@sa415m ~]# strace /bin/ls
execve("/bin/ls", ["/bin/ls"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1429000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="sa415m", ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f16000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=57138, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 57138, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f08000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\320l\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0555, st_size=476584, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 540784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e63000
mprotect(0xb6ed7000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6ee6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x73000) = 0xb6ee6000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libpam.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\30\34\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=42672, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 106852, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e48000
mprotect(0xb6e52000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6e61000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0xb6e61000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libpam_misc.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\\\n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9684, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73936, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e35000
mprotect(0xb6e37000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6e46000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xb6e46000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\250#\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0555, st_size=67284, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 141272, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e12000
mprotect(0xb6e22000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6e31000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xf000) = 0xb6e31000
mmap2(0xb6e33000, 6104, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6e33000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\200Q\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=116992, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 187996, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6de4000
mprotect(0xb6e00000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6e0f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b000) = 0xb6e0f000
mmap2(0xb6e11000, 3676, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6e11000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbe941508) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/neon", 0xbe941508) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l/vfp", 0xbe941508)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/v7l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/v7l", 0xbe941508)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon/vfp", 0xbe941508) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/neon", 0xbe941508)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/vfp", 0xbe941508)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0xbe941508)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon/vfp", 0xbe941508) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/neon", 0xbe941508)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l/vfp", 0xbe941508)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/v7l/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/v7l", 0xbe941508)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/neon/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon/vfp", 0xbe941508)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/neon/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/neon", 0xbe941508)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/vfp/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/vfp", 0xbe941508)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0Lr\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
[...]
```